# Bitmask should be advanced to more possibilieties

Tags: c++, c++11, bitmask

I want to make a bitmask. The following defines are already taken.

```
#define SEC_NO_FLAGS   0x000
#define SEC_ALLOC      0x001
#define SEC_LOAD       0x002
#define SEC_RELOC      0x004
#define SEC_READONLY   0x008
#define SEC_CODE       0x010
#define SEC_DATA       0x020
#define SEC_ROM        0x040
```

Then, I initialize the `uint32_t ptr = 0;` and I can OR it with the defines:

```
ptr |= SEC_ALLOC;
```

Now, I want to extend the defines to:

```
#define SEC_CORE_1       0x080
#define SEC_CORE_2       0x0F0
#define SEC_CORE_3       0x110
#define SEC_CORE_4       0x120
#define SEC_CORE_5       0x140
#define SEC_CORE_6       0x180
```

How should I choose the defines above to have a unique bitmask?

But if I test the bitmask. It prints several c's:

```
std::string
ParseManager::mapFlags(uint64_t flag)
{
  std::string tmp = "";

  if (flag & SEC_ALLOC)
  {
    tmp.append("a");
  }

  if (flag & SEC_CODE)
  {
    tmp.append("x");
  }

  if (flag & SEC_READONLY)
  {
    tmp.append("r");
  }

  if (flag & SEC_DATA)
  {
    tmp.append("w");
  }

  if (flag & SEC_LOAD)
  {
    tmp.append("l");
  }

  if (flag & SEC_CORE_1)
  {
    tmp.append("c1");
  }

  if (flag & SEC_CORE_2)
  {
    tmp.append("c2");
  }

  if (flag & SEC_CORE_3)
  {
    tmp.append("c3");
  }

  if (flag & SEC_CORE_4)
  {
    tmp.append("c4");
  }

  if (flag & SEC_CORE_5)
  {
    tmp.append("c5");
  }

  if (flag & SEC_CORE_6)
  {
    tmp.append("c6");
  }

  return tmp;
}
```

Comment: A clearer way may be to used the constant expressions `1<<0`, `1<<1`, `1<<2` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first block of defined bitmasks expands to binary representataion as follows.

```
#define SEC_NO_FLAGS   0x000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
#define SEC_ALLOC      0x001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0001
#define SEC_LOAD       0x002 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010
#define SEC_RELOC      0x004 0000 0000 0000 0000 0100
#define SEC_READONLY   0x008 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000
#define SEC_CODE       0x010 0000 0000 0000 0001 0000
#define SEC_DATA       0x020 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000
#define SEC_ROM        0x040 0000 0000 0000 0100 0000
```

All of these have exactly one bit set, which is a different bit in every value. The second block of bitmasks looks as follows.

```
#define SEC_CORE_1     0x080 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000
#define SEC_CORE_2     0x0F0 0000 0000 0000 1111 0000
#define SEC_CORE_3     0x110 0000 0000 0001 0001 0000
#define SEC_CORE_4     0x120 0000 0000 0001 0010 0000
#define SEC_CORE_5     0x140 0000 0000 0001 0100 0000
#define SEC_CORE_6     0x180 0000 0000 0001 1000 0000
```

The newly defined bitmasks are different from the previously defined bitmasks, but they share some bits; for instance, `SEC_CORE_2` includes the bit set in `SEC_CODE`. If the values need to be used as bit masks independently from each other, they are not permitted to share the same bits, which can be achieved, for instance, with the following values.

```
#define SEC_CORE_1     0x0100 0000 0000 0001 0000 0000
#define SEC_CORE_2     0x0200 0000 0000 0010 0000 0000
#define SEC_CORE_3     0x0400 0000 0000 0100 0000 0000
#define SEC_CORE_4     0x0800 0000 0000 1000 0000 0000
#define SEC_CORE_5     0x1000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000
#define SEC_CORE_6     0x2000 0000 0010 0000 0000 0000
```

Comment: I am getting always this error: 

warning: integer constant is too large for its type
   if (flag & SEC_CORE_6)